# Poles of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} $ be meromorphic and $\{ z_j \}$ be its poles. In the text I am reading $f$ also satisfies the identity 
$$
f(z)^{-1} = \overline{f(\overline{z})} \qquad \text{for } \operatorname{Re}z >0.
$$ 
It also happens to satisfy the property that 
$$
g(z) := \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}, \qquad z\in \mathbb{C},
$$
is even. Then it states that, consequently, the function $f(z)^{-1}$ will have poles at $\{-z_j \}$. Why?

Comment: The first identity doesn't seem to be necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the derivative of $\log(f)$ is even, $\log(f)$ is odd. That means that $f=e^h$ where $h$ is an odd function. Thus,
$$
f(-z)=e^{h(-z)}=e^{-h(z)}=1/f(z)
$$
Therefore, if $z_j$ is a pole of $f$, $-z_j$ will be a pole of $1/f$.

Since $g$ is even, if there is a pole at the origin, it must have residue $0$ (i.e. the coefficient of $1/z$ must be $0$). Thus, $h$, the anti-derivative of $g$, can be well-defined in a neighborhood of the origin. This is enough to establish that $f(z)f(-z)=1$ in a neighborhood of the origin. By analytic continuation, we can extend this property to the domain of $f$ connected to the origin.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks mate.